Getting this error while loading csv file in databricks
Getting this error while trying to load csv file from Azure datalake gen 2 to databricks notebook. I have created connection of Azure and databricks and followed every procedure.
dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://bronze@awprojectadls.dfs.core.windows.net/")

Error
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'JavaObject'
    [... skipping hidden 1 frame]
File /databricks/python_shell/dbruntime/utils.py:103, in get_max_error_message_length(shell)
    101 def get_max_error_message_length(shell) -> int:
    102     default = 100_000
--> 103     return int(
    104         shell.spark_config.get("spark.databricks.driver.ipykernel.maxErrorMessageLength",
    105                                str(default)) if hasattr(shell, "spark_config") else default) 


Please always include all code, errors (and any textual data) as text, not images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Aside from the fact that the error clearly states the problem, the code tries to turn a JavaObject into an int, what did you do, what is your code. It is impossible to answer your question as is, beyond the answer I just gave

Can you provide your mounting code?
